# How to add new values to dataframe's columns based on specific row without overwrite existing data

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a batch of identifier and a pair of values that behave in following manner within an iteration.
For example,

```
print(indexIDs[i], (coordinate_x, coordinate_y))
```

Sample output looks like

[image]

I would like to add these data into dataframe, where I can use indexIDs[i] as row and append incoming pair of values with same identifier in the next consecutive columns

I have attempted to perform following code, which didn't work.

```
spatio_location = pd.DataFrame()
spatio_location.loc[indexIDs[i], column_counter] = (coordinate_x, coordinate_y)
```

It was an ideal initial to associate indexIDs[i] as row, however I could not progress to take incoming data without overwriting previous dataframe. I am aware it has something to do with the second line which uses "=" sign.

I am aware my second line is keep overwriting previous result over and over again. I am looking for an appropriate way change my second line to insert new incoming data to existing dataframe without overwriting from time to time.

Appreciate your time and effort, thanks.

Comment: whats the desired output?

Comment: @U10-Forward, sorry about re-tag, i am suppose to retain all outputs at n-steps progress. https://imgur.com/MBvRoNc

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confuesed from the nature of coordinate_x (is it a list or what?) anyway maybe try to use `append`

you could define an empty df with three columns

```
df=pd.DataFrame([],columns=['a','b','c'])
```

after populate it with a loop on your lists

```
for i in range TOFILL:
    df=df.append({'a':indexIDs[i],'b':coordinate_x[i],'c':coordinate_y[i]},ignore_index=True)
```

finally set a columns as index

```
df=df.set_index('a')
```

hope it helps

Comment: with proper tune to the 2nd statement, I am able to solve the problem. Suppose b is a column is able to store a list of (coordinate_x and coordinate_y). Although it is not directly solve, but thanks for the insight for tuning.